# Web page can't retrieve data from remote server in Phonegap (but works fine in Chrome)

Tags: javascript, cordova, cors

I am trying to create an Android application using Phonegap 3.1. The app needs to retrieve data from my remote server, which is running Apache with the `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` directive set for the URI the app should be pulling data from. I have `<access subdomains='true' url='*' />` set in Phonegap's config.xml file. The code below works and runs the "success" function if I put the web page into a local Apache directory separate from the server (different machines on different domains in different physical locations) and call it from Chrome, but when I try to call it via Phonegap it throws a less than helpful error of `{"readystste":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}`. The `"readystate":0` looks like it might be an access or cross-site scripting error that's only happening in Phonegap, so I'm willing to believe it's something I need to configure on my end, but I'm going nuts trying to figure out what.

Thanks for any help you can provide. I need to get this running and have been scouring the web for a week trying to get it to work.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/affirmation.css">
  <script src="js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
  <script>

  $.support.cors = true;

  $(document).ready(function(){

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://www.remote.server/info/API',
        datatype: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(
          { method: 'content',
          params: [
            'text passed to function on server' 
          ],
          id: '1' }
        ),
        success: function(response, textstatus, jqxhr) {
        $('#graf1').text(JSON.stringify(response));
        $('#graf3').text(JSON.stringify(textstatus));
        $('#graf6').text(JSON.stringify(jqxhr));
        },
        error: function(jqxhr, textstatus, errorthrown) {
        $('#graf1').text(JSON.stringify(jqxhr));
        $('#graf3').text(JSON.stringify(textstatus));
        $('#graf6').text(JSON.stringify(errorthrown));
        }

      });          
  });

  </script>

</HEAD>
<BODY>
  <DIV ID="header">JSON Server Test</DIV>
  <DIV ID="content">
  <DIV ID="graf1" CLASS="bodytext"></DIV>
  <DIV ID="graf3" CLASS="bodytext"></DIV>
  <DIV ID="graf6" CLASS="bodytext"></DIV>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try putting `<access origin="*" subdomains="true" />` inside the `www/config.xml` file, as per: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Whitelist%20Guide
In your question, you have `url` instead of `origin`.

Another thing I'm thinking of, are you testing with an emulator? If so, are you using the full URL for the remote server or just localhost? Because `localhost` on the emulator will map back to the emulator itself and not to the server you are running on your machine.

Comment: Winner winner chicken dinner! Changing `url` to `origin` did the trick. I'd vote this up if I could but I'm new here so maybe someone will do it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have the permissions for internet use? [PhoneGap Documentation: Connection](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/cordova_connection_connection.md.html)

Comment: thanks for the link, but unfortunately it points to the 2.1 documentation. Phonegap 3.1 is significantly different, and I haven't found any references to Android permissions in the 3.0 (latest) docs yet. The AndroidManifest.xml does have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` already set.

Comment: Sorry, here is a link for the most recent docs. http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0rc1/cordova_connection_connection.md.html#Connection
It's still relevant in 3.0 but depending on how the Phonegap project was created sometimes that permission is not immediately requested.

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything including `<access origin="*" subdomains="true" />` but din't work for me.

then I added

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" spec="~1.2.1" />
```

In my config.xml and it worked.